# DevExpress XAF how to add a control to popup window of an action

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I am having an extremely difficult time trying to figure out how to do what it seems like should be a simple thing within a DevExpress XAF application.

I have figured out how to add a custom action item to the top of a detail view of a business object. All I need to do is to display a popup window that contains a DevExpress Web UI control (ASPxUploadControl, but it could be any control, even a simple ASPxButton). This does not need to be platform-agnostic, it only needs to work in the Web UI app and can be implemented in the Web module and Web UI projects.

None of the DevExpress documentation seems to tie these couple of simple things together, and I can't figure it out. DevExpress support has not been very helpful either - to be clear, they have tried to help me but it seems like I can't get them to actually understand my exact scenario (based on the documentation they point me to, which seems to be way more complex than what I am trying to do).

Has anyone else implemented what i am after within DevExpress XAF? Can anyone with DevExpress XAF experience give me some tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: There is an example that shows how to show a custom control. Does this example help you? https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E911

Comment: The E911 reference is a curious combination of being both too detailed in some respects, and not detailed enough in others. It really didn't help me too much. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the tutorial [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2723). In that example the popup window shows the properties of the `Note` object. You need an object with a property for your file upload. (Make sure you've added the *File Attachments* module).

So create an XPO object (or an EF object if you prefer) similar to the one described [in the documentation for File Attachments](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2658) like this:

```
[NonPersistent]
public class Resume : BaseObject {
   public Resume(Session session) : base(session) {}

   private FileData file;
   [Aggregated, ExpandObjectMembers(ExpandObjectMembers.Never)]
   public FileData File {
      get { return file; }
      set {
         SetPropertyValue("File", ref file, value);
      }
   }
}
```

Now follow the [popup tutorial](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2723), but instead of `Note`, use `Resume`.

Notice that `Resume` is marked `[NonPersistent]`, so it will not save it to the database, but you can get the contents in the `Execute` event. (Of course, if you would prefer to save the attachment to the database instead, use `[DefaultClassOptions]` as in the example for Note).

One more thing - make sure that the popup is opened in edit mode rather than view mode, otherwise the buttons for uploading will not appear.

Comment: That reference (CustomDocument2723) was the closest to what I needed. Thanks for the suggestion. The disconnect comes when I need to put one of the complex DevExpress ASP.NET Webforms UI controls, the ASPxUploadControl, in the popup window of an action, rather than a list or detail view of another BO like Note.

Comment: The XAF framework is this: some very complex things are very easy (e.g., security, reporting, a rich customisable model); some usually easy things are difficult (e.g., non-standard controls, etc.). You get a lot out of the box and there is usually a way to achieve what you need, but it may not be the way you are used to. The File Attachment module already uses the ASPxUploadControl and the XAF way is to create a non-persistent BO and use it in the popup. The advantage to this approach is that the BO gets added to the model, so you can customise layout the same way as everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I'm not using the FileAttachmentBase stuff, just handling the ASPxUploadControl's FilesUploadCompleted event to do manual writes to an Attachments table in the database that only stores the filename and filesystemlocation of uploaded files (and ASPxUploadControl stores files in the filesystem rather than in the database like FileAttachmentBase anyway). After a couple of days of banging on this I have almost gotten it figured out. Once I do I am going to post a youtube video so everyone can see exactly how this is done - with special emphasis on just how to plop any old DevExpress ASP.NET Webforms UI control into the custom action's custom popup window, and how to handle the UI control's events (like for the ASPxUploadControl, the FilesUploadCompleted event). The technical specifics are too verbose to post here.

Comment: I should also mention that the other reason I have to use the ASPxUploadControl rather than the XAF File Attachment module, is because the XAF File Attachment module does not have fully FOUR things that the ASPxUploadControl does: 1) Progress bar, 2) multiple file upload, 3) advanced mode to handle large files in chunks 4) drag-and-drop files. We MAYBE could have lived without #3 and #4 but for the File Attachment module not to at least have #1 and #2 is pretty lacking.